# Environment Hub in a Dev Org (without ISV partnership)

Tags: developer-org, environment-hub

Does Salesforce help in enabling Environment Hub in a standard Dev org (specifically without an ISV partnership)? Is this even possible with dev orgs? Or only available with Enterprise or any paid version/ partnership with SF? Most of my search results in this ref mentions about DE which can be interpreted as a partner dev edition. I'm unable to locate an actual credible information in this regard.

The reason I'm looking for this information is that I'm trying to do a test set-up in my dev org to demonstrate managed package publishing mechanism at a high level.

*[Note that I'm not talking about partner dev editions here. I had previously dabbled with Env Hub & Dev Mgmt Org at my previous employer but they were an ISV partner with premium support.]*

Comment: We have Env Hub in a DE org. As a partner, we went through the partner channel to turn it on. YMMV.

Comment: I guess the DE org you are talking about is actually a partner dev edition, which is different than the standard DE (_that anybody can sign up for_). On this partner dev edition (which would serve as Dev mgmt org), one can create new orgs or connect to a standard dev org. I have no doubt that this can be done if you are partner. My question was specifically targeted on what if you are not a SF partner and want to try this out on normal dev org.

Comment: Our DE org is a standard DE org, not partner dev  or any partner-specific flavor. (We have partner orgs too, this DE org is not one of them). Our understanding is that Env Hub can live anywhere but it's only enabled for partners as a matter of policy. Have you tried talking to your Account Executive about this?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Regarding `Have you tried talking to your Account Executive about this?`, I'm neither a SF partner nor have a paid org and I'm exploring this option on a free dev edition. So, there is no dedicated support or Account executive per se (at the least not to my knowledge).

Comment: Have you tried enabling it? I have 2 DE orgs that have the Dev Hub enabled, one created through Trailhead and one through the 'normal' sign up. The Summer 20 release notes (https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs.htm) and documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_editions_and_allocations.htm) also mention DE orgs. You can have 3 Scratch Orgs, so Dev Hub must be available. Edit: Sorry, I didn't read properly. I thought you meant Dev Hub, but you're talking about Environment Hub.

Comment: @Folkert Dev Hub = scratch orgs only. Env Hub = non-scratch orgs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=environment_hub_intro.htm&type=5):

> Available in: Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited Editions

As such, you can't set it up in a DE (if you could, this page would include Developer as an available edition). You do not need to be an ISV to get Environment Hub, however, you just need a paid org of any of the aforementioned editions. You can always set up your test in production, as there are no settings that are "permanent" aside from enabling the feature itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read through this documentation earlier, but I interpreted it as '_Env Hub would be available by default in these editions, without the need to raise a request with SF support._' I cannot do this `You can always set up your test in production` because this is something I'm trying to do at my personal end and I don't have any paid org.

Comment: @arut I just checked my company's paid org, and we don't have Environment Hub. I'm pretty sure you still need to ask, unless you're specifically a partner (they get it automatically). But DE orgs are not listed in the list of supported orgs, and I presume the documentation is correct.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies my doubts about where env hub is available by default.

Comment: This might be a glitch in the matrix or perhaps I tested Dev Hub in an early stage when they still allowed it in developer orgs, because I have it in my dev org. Edit: I see that @identigral also has this. In my case it might also be possible that I created the dev org when I was working for a partner.